# Preencher data Automaticamente no ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvc, migrations

Ola, tudo bem? Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês, já procurei aqui no forum mas não tive sucesso com os resultados.
Tenho uma pequena aplicação onde eu faço controle de Certificados Digitais, o meu model Certificado é simples conforme abaixo:

Uso Entity Framework e Migrations com SQL SERVER.

**Segue meu Model:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ControleGCD.Models

{
    public class Certificado
    {

        [Key]
        public int CertificadoId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Chave")]
    [MinLength(10,ErrorMessage ="{0} deve conter no mínimo 10 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage ="{0} deve conter entre 10 até 50 caracteres.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Favor preencher a {0} do Certificado")]
    public string CertificadoChave { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve conter no mínimo 10 caracteres.")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "{0} deve conter entre 10 até 50 caracteres.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Favor preencher a {0} do Certificado")]
    public string CertificadoDescricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preço")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false, NullDisplayText = "Sem preço")]
    public decimal CertificadoPreco { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Compra")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]    
    public DateTime CertificadoDtCompra { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vencimento")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CertificadoDtVencimento { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cadastro")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CertificadoDtCadastro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Expira em (dias)")]
    public int CertificadoExpira { get { return (int)CertificadoDtVencimento.Subtract(CertificadoDtCompra).TotalDays; } }

    [Display(Name ="Status")]
    public StatusCertificado CertificadoStatus { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Tipo")]
    public int TipoCertificadoId { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoCertificado TipoCertificado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modelo")]
    public int ModeloCertificadoId { get; set; }
    public virtual ModeloCertificado ModeloCertificado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fornecedor")]
    public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
```

**Reparem que nele tenho um campo data de cadastro onde eu quero preencher automaticamente com a data atual e mostrar na View create.**

**Segue minha View:**

```
@model ControleGCD.Models.Certificado
@{
    /**/

ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cadastro  - Certificado Digital</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/formulario.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <br />
        <div class="panel panel- panel-primary">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4>Cadastro Certificado Digital</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoChave, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificadoChave, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Chave do Certificado" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoChave, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoDescricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificadoDescricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Descrição" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoDescricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FornecedorId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("FornecedorId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FornecedorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CertificadoStatus, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoCertificadoId, "TipoCertificadoId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("TipoCertificadoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoCertificadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModeloCertificadoId, "ModeloCertificadoId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("ModeloCertificadoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ModeloCertificadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoPreco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificadoPreco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0,00", data_tipo = "moeda" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoPreco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoDtCompra, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificadoDtCompra, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Data Compra" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoDtCompra, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoDtVencimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificadoDtVencimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Data Vencimento" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoDtVencimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CertificadoDtCadastro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CertificadoDtCadastro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Data Cadastro" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CertificadoDtCadastro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/mascaras.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/methods_pt.js"></script>
    }
</div>
```

**Segue meu Controller:**

using ControleGCD.Context;
using ControleGCD.Models;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ControleGCD.Controllers
{
    public class CertificadosController : Controller
    {
        private ControleGCDContext db = new ControleGCDContext();

```
    // GET: Certificados
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var certificados = db.Certificados.Include(c => c.Fornecedor).Include(c => c.ModeloCertificado).Include(c => c.TipoCertificado);
        return View(certificados.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Certificados/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Certificado certificado = db.Certificados.Find(id);
        if (certificado == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(certificado);
    }

    // GET: Certificados/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.FornecedorId = new SelectList(db.Fornecedores, "FornecedorId", "FornecedorNome");
        ViewBag.ModeloCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.ModeloCertificados, "ModeloCertificadoId", "ModeloCertificadoDescricao");
        ViewBag.TipoCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.TipoCertificados, "TipoCertificadoId", "TipoCertificadoDescricao");
        Certificado certificado = new Certificado();
        certificado.CertificadoDtCadastro = DateTime.Now;
        return View();
    }

       // POST: Certificados/Create
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CertificadoId,CertificadoChave,CertificadoDescricao,CertificadoPreco,CertificadoDtCompra,CertificadoDtVencimento,CertificadoDtCadastro,CertificadoStatus,TipoCertificadoId,ModeloCertificadoId,FornecedorId")] Certificado certificado)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Certificados.Add(certificado);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.FornecedorId = new SelectList(db.Fornecedores, "FornecedorId", "FornecedorNome", certificado.FornecedorId);
        ViewBag.ModeloCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.ModeloCertificados, "ModeloCertificadoId", "ModeloCertificadoDescricao", certificado.ModeloCertificadoId);
        ViewBag.TipoCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.TipoCertificados, "TipoCertificadoId", "TipoCertificadoDescricao", certificado.TipoCertificadoId);
        return View(certificado);
    }

    // GET: Certificados/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Certificado certificado = db.Certificados.Find(id);
        if (certificado == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.FornecedorId = new SelectList(db.Fornecedores, "FornecedorId", "FornecedorNome", certificado.FornecedorId);
        ViewBag.ModeloCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.ModeloCertificados, "ModeloCertificadoId", "ModeloCertificadoDescricao", certificado.ModeloCertificadoId);
        ViewBag.TipoCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.TipoCertificados, "TipoCertificadoId", "TipoCertificadoDescricao", certificado.TipoCertificadoId);
        return View(certificado);
    }

    // POST: Certificados/Edit/5
    // Para se proteger de mais ataques, ative as propriedades específicas a que você quer se conectar. Para 
    // obter mais detalhes, consulte https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CertificadoId,CertificadoChave,CertificadoDescricao,CertificadoPreco,CertificadoDtCompra,CertificadoDtVencimento,CertificadoDtCadastro,CertificadoStatus,TipoCertificadoId,ModeloCertificadoId,FornecedorId")] Certificado certificado)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(certificado).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.FornecedorId = new SelectList(db.Fornecedores, "FornecedorId", "FornecedorNome", certificado.FornecedorId);
        ViewBag.ModeloCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.ModeloCertificados, "ModeloCertificadoId", "ModeloCertificadoDescricao", certificado.ModeloCertificadoId);
        ViewBag.TipoCertificadoId = new SelectList(db.TipoCertificados, "TipoCertificadoId", "TipoCertificadoDescricao", certificado.TipoCertificadoId);
        return View(certificado);
    }

    // GET: Certificados/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Certificado certificado = db.Certificados.Find(id);
        if (certificado == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(certificado);
    }

    // POST: Certificados/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Certificado certificado = db.Certificados.Find(id);
        db.Certificados.Remove(certificado);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Estou apanhando nisso... Preencher automaticamente o Campo Data de Cadastro com a data atual.
Podem me ajudar por favor?

Agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais "limpo" mandar um valor default para o formulário, é criar uma instância do objeto e popular com os valores default ao dar o GET na ACTION do formulário:

```
public IActionResult Cadastrar() {
   Certificado certificado = new Certificado();
   certificado.CertificadoDtCadastro = DateTime.Now;

   return View(certificado);
}
```

- Substitua o nome do método pelo correto.

Dessa maneira você pode centralizar também os valores default do seu objeto.

Comment: Não tem problema, deve funcionar da mesma forma, troque IActionResult por ActionResult

Comment: Gustavo,
Add as duas linhas, a unica diferença é no return que deixei:
return View(). 
Quando especifiquei o obj certificado dentro do parenteses deu erro. Deixando vazio, o sistema foi compilado normalmente e rodou sem apresentar a data..
O que será que fiz de errado? Tenho que mexer na minha View?
Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Poste o código do seu controller

Comment: Add meu Controller no corpo da minha dúvida Gustavo.

Comment: Estranho ter dado erro de compilação ao adicionar return View(certificado), pois você mesmo usa isso em outros métodos

Comment: Gustavo,
Muito obrigado cara...certamente comi bola em alguma coisa... revisando aqui refiz conforme você me instruiu e deu certo. Agradeço.

Comment: Por favor dê a resposta como aceita amigo :)